# Углы для контейнера

Tags: css3

Очень хочу сделать вот такую рамку для своего контейнера но уже 4 день ничего не выходит. Вот мой код  что я уже смог написать  border: 5px solid #FFCF6E;
clip-path: polygon(20px 0, calc(100% - 20px) 0, 100% 20px, 100% calc(100% - 20px), calc(100% - 20px) 100%, 20px 100%, 0 calc(100% - 20px), 0 20px);
border: 5px solid;
border-image-slice: 1;

border-image-source: linear-gradient(to bottom, #7C5C28 0%, #7C5C28 50%, rgba(124,92,40,0) 100%);
padding: 1em 2em;
https://i.stack.imgur.com/YX2zV.png

Comment: Воспользуйтесь фрагментом кода, чтобы привести код.

Comment: И картинку нормально вставьте пожалуйста

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Используйте псевдоэлементы, как фон, применив к ним *clip-path* (Вы можете изменить размер, ухватив блок за правый нижний угол):

```css
/* For example only --> */ body{margin:0;min-height:100vh;display:flex;flex-flow:column nowrap;justify-content:space-around;align-items:center;background-color:#000;background-image:url('https://i.stack.imgur.com/m9NKc.png'),radial-gradient(#fff8,#000f);background-position:0 0;background-repeat:no-repeat;background-size:auto}

.wrap {
  position: relative;
  width: 400px; height: 160px;
  font: bold 16px/1.3em sans-serif;
  padding: 1em;
  color: #f1d476;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  /* For example only */
  overflow: hidden;
  resize: both;
}
.wrap::before,
.wrap::after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%; left: 50%; z-index: -1;
  width: 100%; height: 100%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
.wrap::before {
  background-image: linear-gradient(#745225, #281d0b);
  clip-path: polygon(13px 0, calc(100% - 13px) 0, 100% 13px, 100% calc(100% - 13px), calc(100% - 13px) 100%, 13px 100%, 0 calc(100% - 13px), 0 13px);
}
.wrap::after {
  background-image: linear-gradient(#4c300e, #090601);
  clip-path: polygon(14px 2px, calc(100% - 14px) 2px, calc(100% - 2px) 14px, calc(100% - 2px) calc(100% - 14px), calc(100% - 14px) calc(100% - 2px), 14px calc(100% - 2px), 2px calc(100% - 14px), 2px 14px);
}
```

```html
<div class="wrap">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Fugiat provident iure quam ab rem, quod voluptate eligendi nostrum sequi molestiae harum. Nam ducimus quas iusto non assumenda necessitatibus quo deserunt.</div>
```

Comment: Вы мне очень помогли с контейнером, но я столкнулся ещё с одной проблемой добавление изображение на рамку, могли бы вы посмотреть? https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1508243/%d0%98%d0%b7%d0%be%d0%b1%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b6%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d0%b4%d0%bb%d1%8f-%d1%82%d0%be%d0%bf-%d0%b1%d0%be%d1%80%d0%b4%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b0

Comment: @КубаБрежнев: проверьте.